# Deleting tensorflow dataset graph each iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, memory-management, tensorflow-datasets

I need to manipulate a tensorflow dataset over many iterations.  However, when manipulating the dataset using map, I'm getting memory issues.  I'm pretty sure that tensorflow is drawing a function graph each time calling map, and I would like to delete that graph each iteration.

I'm trying to use `tf.keras.backend.clear_session` and deleting it manually, but I'm still running into memory issues.

```
for i in range(10000):
  keras.backend.clear_session()
  ds = tf_dataset.map(map_fn)
  del ds
```

Comment: Can you show your `map_fn` function?